# I am trying to send post request from postman but at first request got accepted, but the data are stored as null

Tags: php, mysql, sql

*// mysql table creation*

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `designation` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `cpassword` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `age` int NOT NULL,
  `phone` int NOT NULL,
  `pincode` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

*// Postman post request*

```
  {
   "name":"krithi",
   "age":15,
   "gender":"female",
   "phone":1234567890,
   "designation":"volunteer",
   "address":"chennai",
   "pincode":90,
   "password":"ac",
   "cpassword":"ac",
   "email":"abc@gmail.com"

}
```

*// output  in postman*

```
{"code":1010,"message":"Data integrity violation"}
```

But it works well for get request. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
I changed my table into a simpler one
```

CREATE TABLE `d` (
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
    and my json is`
       {

```
    "name" : "abc"
    }
*and the response is* 

    {
    "code": 9999,
    "message": "Argument 1 passed to Tqdev\\PhpCrudApi\\Database\\ColumnsBuilder::quoteColumnName() must be an instance of Tqdev\\PhpCrudApi\\Column\\Reflection\\ReflectedColumn, null given, called in C:\\Users\\vimy9\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\clone\\php-crud-api\\api.php on line 4892"
}
```

Comment: show the table definition (`SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}`), what code are you executing? What is the specific command being generated? Welcome to SO. Please provide mode details up front.

Comment: You have to specify a primary key on the simpler table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `id int NOT NULL` in your query but you're not passing an ID while inserting, if you want it to be auto generated, it should be `id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: or better 'int unsigned not null auto increment`

Comment: The error got cleared, thank you for your solution.